# Is license need for free wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, licensing

I'm developing a new WordPress, So i'm a beginner. I'm referring a plugin to create a readme.txt file. I've seen that two lines.

License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

one question raised in my mind. How to create wordpress license and is license need?

Comment: If you used any other persons code. or part of the code files. you have to specify its license. and also if you are providing to WordPress plugins directory, just submit it there. It will be automatically GPL licensed one. But if the code should be completely yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on submitting the plugin to the WordPress Repository then it is not technically required **but** by submitting it you automatically agree that the entire plugin is "considered GPLv2 or later." - [The Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/) says this in regards to [Plugins added to the Repository](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/)

> 1) Your plugin must be compatible with the GNU General Public License
>   v2, or any later version. We strongly recommend using the same license
>   as WordPress — “GPLv2 or later.”
>
> *Note:* This rule applies to everything in the plugin. This includes code, data, and images, even if you did not create that particular
>   piece. All third-party libraries must also be compatible. For a
>   specific list of compatible licenses, please read the GPL-Compatible
>   license list on gnu.org. Double check your licensing before you start
>   writing your plugin.
>
> 2) **If you don’t specify a compatible license** (such as in a
>   license.txt file or referencing or declaring a license somewhere in
>   the code or readme.txt file), what you check in is **considered GPLv2
>   or later**. By committing code to our repository at all, you accept
>   this condition.

Also from the handbook, here's some instructions on including a license: [Including a Software License](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/including-a-software-license/)